# How to create new object from two already existing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following table in db

```
create_table "rates", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "base_currency"
t.string "target_currency"
t.float "value"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

I have some rates in it. 
e.g.:

```
EUR | USD | 1.16
EUR | CAD | 1.49
EUR | NZD | 1.68
```

How can I create new pairs, like:

```
USD | CAD | nnn
NZD | CAD | yyy
```

and so on?

I know how to do it manually:

```
f = Rate.first
l = Rate.last
n = Rate.new(base_currency:f.target_currency, target_currency:l.target_currency, value: f.value/l.value)
```

But I don't know how to iterate over the whole array.
Appreciate for help!

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to calculate the rate on demand?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: It depends how you want to pair them. Do you need to create a  Rate based on 2 random set of Rates ?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use a `gem` that already provides all of this functionality and more like [`money`](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) this gem allows you to specify a "bank" and the conversions are handled for you based on the current rates from places like [Google Currency](https://finance.google.com/finance/converter)

Comment: @Cyzanfar I have 32 currencies, and I need to create pairs of each of them. It will be 1024 combinations.

Comment: @engineersmnky that is too easy, I want to understand how to do it. But thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Does the order of the pair matter? that's important because if it does then you'd have 496 combinations and not 1024. The math is 32!/2!30! = 496. Also I agree with you @user2392771, I'd do it myself too rather than using a gem

Comment: @Cyzanfar I want to get all pairs with EUR, then, for example, all pairs with USD,then all pairs with CZE and so on. I think that I could use uniq method or something similar to get those pairs unique later.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by

[product method](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/product)
which multiplies arrays, so I get all combinations I need